# Suppose $S,T\in\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$ are self-adjoint. Prove that $ST$ is self-adjoint if and only if $ST=TS$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $S,T\in\mathcal L \left({V}\right)$ are self-adjoint. Prove that $ST$ is self-adjoint if and only if $ST=TS$.

### My attempt

Since $ST$ is self-adjoint,
$ST=(ST)^*=T^*S^*=TS$

Comment: You have a typo in your attempt. $(ST)^* = T^*S^*$.

Comment: Fixed. Is this enough to prove both directions? I feel like it's too short

Comment: You should write a proof in the other direction.

Comment: Showing that $(ST)^* = T^*S^* = TS$ is enough. The self-adjoint condition is literally just $(ST)^* = ST$.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt proves one implication (modulo a typo, because $(ST)^*=T^*S^*$).

For the converse, if $ST=TS$, then
$$(ST)^*=T^*S^*=TS=ST.
$$